# How to quickly select zone from all lines vertically in vim?

Tags: vim

I want to select all the columns `id=""` in all lines.
1.
to move cursor on i in the first line,
and press <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>v</kbd>,move right arror key to select `id=""`.

[image]

2. to press  `8j` to select all the zone  vertically.

[image]

There is a disadvantage for this method that to count lines number to write before `j`.

If to  press <kbd>G</kbd> directly,it display as below.

[image]

How to quickly select zone from all lines vertically in vim?

Comment: Alternatively you if this is something you do often you may want to look at [textobj-word-column.vim](https://github.com/coderifous/textobj-word-column.vim). Its fairly magical and not perfect, but it might meet your needs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might be looking for a setting named 'nosol'.
Try ':set nosol', then <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>v</kbd>, <kbd>G</kbd> will behave the way you like it.
See more details [startofline](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27startofline%27)